# What is the difference between creating a new date using momentJS versus using Javascript new Date()?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

if I console log the two I get the same result but for some reason the result of the third console is false which means there is some difference! Any help is appreciated.

```
 console.log(new Date());
 console.log(moment(new Date()).toDate());
 console.log(moment(new Date()).toDate() == new Date());
```

The following is the result I get on the console:

```
Wed Jul 08 2015 15:55:30 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
Wed Jul 08 2015 15:55:30 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
false
```

Comment: no two objects are the same in JS

Comment: Consider `new Date(0) == new Date(0) === false`

Comment: Also, `moment(new Date())` is just the same as `moment()`.   And, if you want to compare a moment with another moment or with a date, use the [`isSame`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing `Date` objects, but you should really be comparing their *values*:

```
console.log(moment(new Date()).toDate().getTime() == (new Date()).getTime());
console.log(+(moment(new Date()).toDate()) == +(new Date()));
```

More discussion on this here: [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492994/74757)